# Installing python2 using homebrew

Tags: python, python-2.7, homebrew

I am trying to install Python 2 through homebrew and I get the following error:

```
$ brew install python
Error: python-python already installed
To install this version, first `brew unlink python`
```

Following this advice gives me

```
brew unlink python
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/python
```

There is nothing Python-related in /usr/local/Cellar. I have tried brew prune/doctor/update/cleanup and purged the cache to no avail. What can I do to install Python 2 using homebrew?

Comment: When you run "python" in terminal what output does it give?

Comment: I get the following output:
`Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 14 2015, 19:46:27)
    [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin 
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>>`

Comment: you could try `brew install python2`. also could try `brew unlink python-python` (doubt would work though)